# Raspberry pi 2 - Multi purpose > Media center + other task

Tags: ssh, raspbmc, media-server

I would like to know if it is possible to use the raspberry pi 2 plugged on my tv so that it is always running a fullscreen app like xbmc or plex media theater, and in the same time be able to connect into it via ssh to work and run some nodejs script without disturbing/interrupting the media center.

If so, what distribution should I use? Would raspbmc or raspbian be the better choice?

I read that plex on pi is running with rasplex which is based on openelec (a read-only system), does that mean that it is impossible to do other task like nodejs etc and having plex at the same time on a pi 2?

Comment: Raspbian is probably the more appropriate general purpose OS, although you *should* be able to get all the same software on raspmc anyway, I think.  As for doing two things at once, working on code via `ssh` generally won't require much from the system except when you are testing it.

Comment: I agree, this should be no problem. Not much more to say though so I won't make it an answer.

Comment: Thanks, what about plex, is it possible to install it on raspbian ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspbmc is based on debian, so there is no reason why it shouldn't work. Depending on exactly what you are planning to run besides the media center, it should be no problem. If you prioritize a glitch free media experience, you could make sure the other thing (node.js, for example) runs on a lower priority. Have a look at `man renice`.